# Docusign listener no longer downloading pushed envelopes

Tags: php, rest, listener, docusignapi

So a few weeks ago we switched over our Docusign demo account to live production. Since then our listener is no longer downloading the envelopes and PDfs. This is the URL code for it to listener for:

```
$postBackPath = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$postBackPath .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Can somebody please give us some direction as to what's wrong? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found that there was a hanging break tag that was left from one of our developers. Problem solved.